# Using "-t" option inside a requirements.txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

When I have, for example, a `requirements-dev.txt` and a `requirements.txt`, I know I can have `-r requirements.txt` inside `requirements-dev.txt`, for example, and running `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt` would install packages from both files.

That said, I was certain that any install option would work fine inside a requirements file. Turns out that when I place inside a requirements file something like:

`mypackage==1.0.0 -t /path/to/local/dir`

I get:

`pip: error: no such option: -t`

while running `pip install mypackage==1.0.0 -t /path/to/local/dir` works just fine. For complicated reasons, I need to place multiple packages in one requirements file, where some packages must target one directory, others must target another, and so goes on.

Any solutions to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t /path/to/install
```

This should work. It worked for me.

If you want different modules to be installed to different locations, then I think you might have to put them into multiple requirements text files. This is at least as far as I know

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. :( But thanks a lot for this answer!

Answer (score 7):

As of today (in *pip* version *21.2.4*), the `-t, --target <dir>` option is not supported in `requirements.txt` files. The [section "*Requirements File Format*" of *pip*'s *User guide*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) lists the currently supported options:

> - `-i`, `--index-url`
> - `--extra-index-url`
> - `--no-index`
> - `-c`, `--constraint`
> - `-r`, `--requirement`
> - `-e`, `--editable`
> - `-f`, `--find-links`
> - `--no-binary`
> - `--only-binary`
> - `--prefer-binary`
> - `--require-hashes`
> - `--pre`
> - `--trusted-host`
> - `--use-feature`